# SQL Query for SCCM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

I created SQL query to get some data that I need.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CPU.SystemName0) AS [Computer Name], 
CS.Manufacturer0 AS [Make], 
CS.Model0 AS [Type], 
OS.Caption0 AS [Operating System],
OS.BuildNumber0 AS [OS Build Number],
OS.Version0 AS [OS Version],
CS.SystemType0 AS [Architecture], 
CS.PrimaryOwnerName0 [Primary User],
CPU.Name0 AS [CPU Model],
COUNT(CPU.ResourceID) AS [Number of CPUs], 
CPU.NumberOfCores0 AS [Number of Cores per CPU], 
CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0 AS [Logical CPU Count], 
MAX(OU.System_OU_Name0) AS [OU] FROM [dbo].[v_GS_PROCESSOR] CPU LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS ON CS.ResourceID = CPU.ResourceID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_RA_System_SystemOUName OU ON CS.ResourceID = OU.ResourceID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_GS_Operating_System OS ON CS.ResourceID = OS.ResourceID WHERE OS.Caption0 NOT LIKE '%server%'
GROUP BY CS.Manufacturer0, CS.PrimaryOwnerName0, OS.BuildNumber0, OS.Version0, CS.Model0, OS.Caption0, CS.SystemType0, CPU.SystemName0, CPU.Name0, CPU.NumberOfCores0, CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0, OU.System_OU_Name0
ORDER BY [Computer Name] ASC
```

On my output, this is correct: Computer Name, Type, Operating System.

For OS Version I want 1909 or 20H2, and I get 10.0.18636 and something like that.

Also my Primary User return Null, I want to have Primary User and Last Log On User, also I would like to use total amount of RAM on that machine and free HDD space. So if can someone help me it will be great.

Many thanks

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (all as formatted text, not images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT CPU.SystemName0 AS...` to make code clearer!

Comment: SQL Server 2017. I try to run query on my DB MS SQL Server Managment Studio

Comment: However, GROUP BY returns no duplicates, so no need to do SELECT DISTINCT here!

Comment: Having a `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` is normally a strong indicator you have a problem. Either the `DISTINCT` is redundent, as the `GROUP BY` has already separated your data into **distinct** groups, *or* your `GROUP BY` is wrong as it's separating into too many groups.